# Perl Script Not Running in Java

Tags: java, perl

I am writing code to run a perl script from java. The command I am providing to java program  is working perfectly fine through shell. However, the same command returns an exit code 2 when supplied to Runtime's exec() method. Why this is happening ?

My code is :

```
package org.nlp.rishabh;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class ReferenceExtractor {
public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception {

    String parscitCommand = "/home/rishabh/Desktop/parscit/bin/citeExtract.pl ";
    String parscitOptions = "-m ";
    String parscitAction = "extract_all ";
    String paperPath = "/home/rishabh/Desktop/aas.txt";
    String xml = null;

    String command = parscitCommand + parscitOptions + parscitAction + paperPath;
    System.out.println( command );

    try {
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process pr = runtime.exec( command );
//      Process pr = runtime.exec( new String[] { "perl", parscitCommand, parscitOptions, parscitAction, paperPath } );

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( pr.getInputStream() ) );
        String temp;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        while ( ( temp = reader.readLine() ) != null ) {
            sb.append( temp );
        }

        xml = sb.toString();

        int returnVal = pr.waitFor();
        System.out.println( returnVal );
    } catch ( Exception e ) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println( xml );
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your file is in your desktop. You are probably running the java code in a way that makes it run as another user with no permission to your desktop.

Try either moving the file to a common location or checking the user running the java process (are you using a web container like tomcat? just running the JVM instance thru console?)

Answer (score 0):

Perl script is not an executable program. It is a script - just a text file. When you are running it using shell like  `./myscript.pl` you are utilizing the feature of `sh` - the linux shell that parses the first line of your script, extracts `!#/bin/perl` and *really* runs your script as following:

`/bin/perl myscript.pl`

When you are running perl script from java you have to do something similar. Either run script using `perl` command or (probably) using `/bin/sh myscript.pl`. I am not sure the last version will work but try it. Theoretically it should.

Comment: I think that - so long as the Perl script is `chmod`ed correctly and has a shebang line - this shouldn't be an issue.